How to delete parenthesis in Vim while keeping nested parenthesis intact?
I want to remove a sets of parenthesis in a large tex document I am editing in vim.
The text is of this kind:
\foo{ \bar{ \john{ TEXT } more text } my text}

and I would like to have this as an output if I want to remove \bar
\foo{ \john{ TEXT } more text my text}

clearly a similar expected output in the case for which I want to remove foo is
 \bar{ \john{ TEXT } more text } my text

I have tried via regex (not much of great user)
%s/\\foo{\([^{}]*\)}/\1/gc

and this has resulted in not being able to handle the nested parenthesis as indicated above.
From what I see vim has some way to find corresponding parenthesis as these are highlighted, even when there is nested parenthesis sets. Can this be leveraged some some how?

There's also the vim-latex plugin which might offer a command for this kind of editing.

If this ouput is ok:
\foo{  \john{ TEXT } more text  my text}

You can use:
:%norm/\\bar^Mdt{di}va}p

Where ^M is a literal newline character typed via CTRL-V+Enter.
Explanation:

:% for all lines
norm run a normal mode command
/\\bar search for \bar
^M type enter to run the search
dt{ delete until the next {
di} delete from within the brace pair
va} visually select the empty brace pair
p paste the yanked register over the visual selection

The above works fine by swapping in \foo for the search/deletion as well.

This is basically an extension of: How to quickly remove a pair of parentheses, brackets, or braces in Vim?
Pure regex is not well suited for this, as it's intended for regular languages and nesting is generally too complex for it to handle.

This has worked well thank you! I guess with /gc it would ask me for confirmation?

You can only use the c flag with :s[ubstitute] unfortunately. There is also :con[firm], but that does not work with :norm[al].

@Jpk appending the c flag will make Vim ask for confirmation. Appending g will replace multiple matches in one line (which may or may not be what you want to do). This is documented in :help :s_c and :help :s_g, respectively.

The universal and simple approach is "to cut and put back". That is, cut inside of bar's {}; then delete bar itself; then put that inner block back.
If the cursor is on bar's { then it is done like this
di{"_daWP

Can you explain how this deals with avoiding that the second delete overwrites the contents of the first delete, so that the first deleted content can be put back? It might have to do with ", and what role does _ play?

@mkrieger1 see :help "_. It's Vim's black hole register. Everything you put in there is gone for good.

TL;DR:

To delete once:
dt{%x``x


To repeat the process (and trim spaces):
inoremap <expr> µ substitute(@", '\v^\s*(.{-})\s*$', '\1', '')
%g/\\bar/exe "normal /\\\\bar\<cr>dt{\<right>di{\"_c%µ"




Regexes are too limited: they cannot handle recursion.
The approach I've been using for ages is:

delete \bar and move the cursor to the opening {
delete the pair

jump to the corresponding pair %
delete the character x (or dw in your case because of the space)
jump back to the other character of the pair: double back-tick
and delete the character (or dt{ in your case because of the space)



I have the second part (from points to 2.1 to 2.4) in a mapping (that can easily adapted to replacing with another pair...). You can find it in the venerable auctex.vim. I've  tweaked it in my lh-brackets plugin. And you'll find equivalent in surround.
However for some reasons I cannot use it with g+normal to repeat it. I end up with the same solution as ruola
%g/\\bar/exe "normal /\\\\bar\<cr>dt{\<right>di{\"_d%P"

Then there is the question of trimming the spaces. It could be possible thanks to <c-r>=substitute(@", '^\s*\(.\{-}\)\s*$', '\1', '')<cr> instead of the last P. But given the number of backslashes to double (or more), I've stopped the obfuscation here.
It could be put into an expression mapping though, and it would become what I've written in the summary
PS: I you want to confirm before each substitution, I have a :ConfirmGlobal command in my library plugin: lh-vim-lib.
ConfirmGlobal#\\bar#exe "normal /\\\\bar\<cr>dt{\<right>di{\"_c%µ"

